# return int of a find query cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to get an integer value of the amount field in my views tables.
I am able to find the value but not return it as an int

```
$amount = $views
            ->find()
            ->select('amount')
            ->where(['date'=>$todaysdate])
            ->first();

        echo $amount;
```

this echos out { "amount": 2 }.
How would i just get an int variable with the 2?

Comment: That's really just CakePHP 101, I don't think that it's of much use for future readers. **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessing-entity-data**

Comment: Sorry, I tried a lot of stuff but nothing really worked. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should use: `echo $amount->amount`. You should spend some time reading the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessing-entity-data).